# Plotting chart with rounded rectangle in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, charts, visualization, plotly

I found an interesting chart illustrating the specific bands of different trace chemical atmospheric species that can be used for detecting on satellite.

[image]

The figure above use rounded rectangle presented for the spectral measurement range.

I want to reproduce this kind of art with python.

For now, I could use `Plotly` package for plotting table in the same style.

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.tools import FigureFactory as FF 
fig = go.Figure()
data_matrix = [['Tracer gas/nm', '200', '300','400','500'],['HCHO', "", ],
               ['CHOCHO',],['BrO', ], ['O3', ],['O2', ],['NO2',]]

table = FF.create_table(data_matrix)
py.iplot(table, filename='simple_table')
# py.image.save_as(fig, filename='a-simple-plot.png')
```

The figure shows like this:

[image]
But I found two tricky problems:

(1) I couldn't save the chart into figure.

(2) I couldn't plot the rounded rectangle on the chart.

Any advice with better solution would be appreciated!